# Ties versus corvettes?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

I just read about the rebels 2nd season (siege of lothal). 
There I read that a single tie was able to take it up with corvettes.

The massive skills of the said tie fighters pilot aside how can the tie even
damage the corvettes from the outside? (that seems to me as if a snow speeder is trying to shoot an AT-AT "Our guns do no damage. Their deflectors are too strong")

Is there any info how it can be that the tie was able to effectively damage the corvettes?

Answer (score 4):

I'll put the answer as a spoiler, since you seem to be trying to avoid spoiling.

I presume the scenario you are referring to is

> the scene where [Darth Vader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker#The_apprentice_lives) attacks the Rebels while flying a TIE Advanced X1.

The reason this is possible is because

> of the TIE Advanced's [technical specifications](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TIE_Advanced_x1). It is particularly effective against shielded targets - one of the key advantages Rebel starfighters possess over Imperial starfighters. Unlike the generic TIE Fighter, the TIE Advanced's design focuses on quality over quantity, and so is built to a level of sophistication matching or even surpassing Rebel starfighters. Using Legends as a reference, it is capable of fighting an X-Wing to a draw.

Applying this back to the scene at hand,

> the only advantages a corvette has against smaller and faster starfighters are its shields and defensive cannons. The TIE Advanced is capable of penetrating those shields. In the hands of the best starfighter pilot of the galaxy during the Clone Wars, it's little wonder it is able to evade enemy fire and decimate the Rebel fleet so overwhelmingly.

Comment: yepp meaning that scene. Althoug has you state that tie versoin can ignore shields....any infos on why a normal tie can't do that? (as I always thought its because they move so close to the vessel they are operating within the shields radio and thus ignore them

Comment: @Thomas In that particular scene, the TIE is quite far from the ship. Ship shields usually seem to hug the ship's profile. The wiki article mentions advanced targeting systems, which suggests an ability to identify and lock on to vulnerabilities in the shields.

Comment: @Thomas The normal TIE Fighter is evolved from the Jedi Interceptor of the Clone Wars, featuring many normally important systems stripped away (Jedi don't need them) to reduce weight and increase speed and agility. This design persisted, but it doesn't work as well for non-Force sensitive pilots of the Empire. If you put our particular pilot in a normal TIE Fighter, he can probably still rout Phoenix Squadron, but this better TIE model gives the extra power needed to do the rest.

Comment: @Thomas Also, regardless of anything, a typical fighter craft is meant to fight other fighter craft, so that more specialized craft which are more vulnerable to fighters - like bombers etc. - can succeed at their missions. Big ships aren't meant to be downed by fighters who only have blaster cannons and weaker concussion missiles - that's the job for bombs and proton torpedoes. This particular TIE...look at as the equivalent of a "hero vehicle" in games.